# Need work-around for "ternary operator" in VHDL constants

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I have some Verilog code as follows:

```
module bus_fifo #(
    parameter DEPTH_WIDTH = 0,
    parameter DATA_WIDTH = 0
) (
    input  wire                    clk,
    input  wire                    rst,

    input  wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]       wr_data_i,
    input  wire                wr_en_i,

    output wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]       rd_data_o,
    input  wire                        rd_en_i,

    output wire                full_o,
    output wire                        empty_o
);

localparam DW = (DATA_WIDTH  == 10) ? 4 : DATA_WIDTH;
localparam AW = DEPTH_WIDTH>>2;

endmodule
```

I want syntactically valid VHDL that does the same thing:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity bus_fifo is
    generic(
        DEPTH_WIDTH               : integer := 0;
        DATA_WIDTH                : integer := 0
    );
    port(
        clk                       : in    std_logic;
        rst                       : in    std_logic;
        wr_data_i                 : in    std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        wr_en_i                   : in    std_logic;
        rd_data_o                 : out   std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        rd_en_i                   : in    std_logic;
        full_o                    : out   std_logic;
        empty_o                   : out   std_logic        
    );
end entity;

architecture bus_fifo of bus_fifo is
    constant   DW         : integer := (DATA_WIDTH  == 10) ? 4 : DATA_WIDTH;
    constant   AW         : integer := DEPTH_WIDTH>>2;
    signal     write_pointer;            : std_logic_vector(AW downto 0);
    signal     read_pointer;             : std_logic_vector(AW downto 0);
    signal     empty_int                 : std_logic;
    signal     full_or_empty             : std_logic;
begin

end architecture;
```

The problem i'm having is that VHDL does't support ternary operator and generates and ERROR message. I'm wondering if there's a VHDL solution to do something similar to what i'm doing in Verilog?

Comment: A function is the only way to do it in VHDL 2008 and previous.

Comment: I question that this assignment makes sense altogether. If `DATA_WIDTH` is 9 or 11, `DW` is 9 or 11, too, but if `DATA_WIDTH` is 10, `DW` is supposed to be 4!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VHDL - IF alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408170/vhdl-if-alternative)

Answer (score 3):

I usually use a function (named "If Then Else" = ite) to work around the lack of a ternary operator in VHDL.

```
function ite(b: boolean; x, y: integer) return integer is begin
    if (b) then
        return x;
    else
        return y;
    end if;
end function ite;
```

Usage like this:

```
constant foo : integer := ite(SOME_INTEGER = 42, 1337, 4711);
```

You can overload this function for different return types. Note that the boolean expression must be constant at evaluation time when used to initialize a constant.
A more realistic example, a recipe I often use:

```
entity foo is
  generic (
    DEBUG_LVL : integer := 0
  )
...
attribute MARK_DEBUG : string;
...
signal my_signal : std_logic;
attribute MARK_DEBUG of my_signal : signal is ite(DEBUG_LVL >= 1, "TRUE", "FALSE");
```

This last example of course requires a "ite function" with the signature

```
function ite(b: boolean; x, y: string) return string;
```

Answer (score 1):

VHDL 2019 adds conditional assignment of initial values:

```
constant DW : integer := 4 when (DATA_WIDTH = 10) else DATA_WIDTH;
```

Expect vendor support (especially Xilinx) by the year 2029.

Comment: Without vendors participating in the standardization process it reminds me of a joke about making [English the standard language of the European Union](http://www.ahajokes.com/eng011.html). The lobster's bean counters notice the cost of repairing reddened integument as VHDL is slowly transformed into SystemVerilog. Will it encounter heat death first?

Comment: @user1155120 I just started at a company which uses VHDL but allow me to use Verilog. After two month they are considering switching. It reminds me of the time all the programmers **had** to learn Pascal whilst the industry used C.

Comment: I am somewhat convinced particular HDL design entry, design validation and verification methodologies can't dominate in the long run. They don't scale well with design and device size increases. If VHDL doesn't 'catch up' to System Verilog the end result will be the same.

Comment: I had got some impression that full on SV was getting too overblown for some, and they were pushing for more formal. Its probably sales schpiel.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and call the function in the evaluation of the generic.